# Paginate in revert order with mongoose-paginate-v2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Is it possible to paginate mongodb in revert order, using mongoose-paginate-v2 given that I have field: createdAt.
For example, my collection have docs: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
1 is the first doc to be created, 10 is the lastest/newest doc.
When I use mongoose-paginate-v2 to paginate that collection, the pagination work this way:
with page size = 3, it returns: **page1: 1-2-3, page2: 4-5-6, page3: 7-8-9, page4: 10**.
How can I use mongoose-paginate-v2 to have result like:
**page1: 10-9-8, page2: 7-6-5, page3: 4-3-2, page4: 1**
This is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `sort` option as an argument to paginate method as per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2).

E.g.

```
const options = { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}

Model.paginate(yourQuery, options)
```